# T-SQL to add a column bound to a existing default constraint

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, constraints, default, alter-table

I have a DEFAULT constraint created in the database, which I want to share among several tables, and I want to script an unique alter table statement for adding a field in that tables as follows:

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD MyField NOT NULL DEFAULT(DF_EXISTING_DEFAULT)
```

The following error ocurrs:

```
Msg 128, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
The name "DF_EXISTING_DEFAULT" is not permitted in this context. Valid expressions are constants, constant expressions, and (in some contexts) variables. Column names are not permitted.
```

Notice that the default value is already defined in DF_EXISTING_DEFAULT, I don't want to write it again. How can I do it? Any reason I shouldn't do it? Is it a t-sql limitation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You actually can do it but the mechanism to do so is deprecated so shouldn't be used.

You can [`CREATE DEFAULT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173565.aspx) object and then use [`sp_bindefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177503.aspx).

There is no non deprecated replacement. If the logic for the default is complex you could put it in a scalar UDF to avoid repeating yourself.

Comment: Well, the default is not complex (e.g. DEFAULT('A simple text'), but it can change in the future. In this case, is UDF the only way to avoid that "code duplication"? The main objective at this moment is to keep a *single* default and to avoid those sql automatic constraint naming.

Comment: @natenho - Yes. A default *constraint* can't be shared between columns  and there are no user defined global variables in SQL Server so to avoid repeating `'A simple text'` in the constraint definitions themselves this is the only way. You could also store it in a table but that would also require a UDF to access. The advantage of storing in a table might be easier maintenance (altering the UDF definition would require dropping all defaults referencing it) but hardcoded in the UDF would be more efficient and in constraint definition itself more so. So trading performance vs maintainability.

Comment: Regarding "can't be shared"...when you use `sp_binddefault` for the same DF in multiple table/columns, aren't you sharing the constraint? At least I can't see new constraints being created.

Comment: @natenho - That is sharing a default *object* not default *constraint*. Trying to bind a constraint gives `Cannot bind default 'X'. The default must be created using the CREATE DEFAULT statement.` (at least on my version of SQL Server)

Comment: If I understood what you said, `EXECUTE sp_bindefault N'dbo.DF_EXISTING_DEFAULT', N'dbo.MyTable.MyField'` works in SQL 2008 for every table I want to bind.

Comment: @natenho - `CREATE TABLE T1(X INT CONSTRAINT DF DEFAULT 0);CREATE TABLE T2(X INT);EXEC sp_bindefault 'DF' , 'T2.X'` definitely doesn't work for me on 2008.

Comment: I meant `CREATE DEFAULT [dbo].[DF] AS 0
CREATE TABLE T1 (X INT);
CREATE TABLE T2 (X INT);
EXEC sp_bindefault 'DF', 'T1.X';
EXEC sp_bindefault 'DF', 'T2.X';`

Comment: Yes that's a (deprecated) default **object**. Not a (non deprecated) default **constraint**.

Comment: Now I see, from [msdn](http://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms173565.aspx)`CREATE DEFAULT`: This feature will be removed in a future version of Microsoft SQL Server. Avoid using this feature in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use this feature. Instead, use default definitions created using the DEFAULT keyword of ALTER TABLE or CREATE TABLE.